# Как вывести запросом дни рождения выпадающие на текущую и на следующую недели?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime, sqlite3

Как сделать запросы SQLite по датам чтобы выводил информацию (дат рождения) на текущую неделю и на следующую неделю?

Запрос выводит данные (дни рождения) на завтрашнюю дату:

```
def data_n_mess_new():
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT full_name, data_n, photo 
             FROM dovidnyk 
             WHERE strftime('%d-%m', data_n) = strftime('%d-%m', 'now', '+1 day')"""
    cursor.execute(sql,)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    
    for fn in result:
```

Comment: `strftime('%W','now')` - понедельник текущей недели , и если так работает, `strftime('%W','now', '+2 week')` - понедельник через 2 недели

Comment: @splash58 Что-то нет так, некоторые даты он не выводит, я так понимаю что это зависит от года рождения. Формат столбца "data_n" DATETIME,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример исходной таблицы:

```
sqlite> select * from tab;
user_id  dob
-------  ----------
1        1990-05-04
2        2000-05-01
3        2001-05-10
4        2002-05-16
5        2002-05-17
```

выбираем даты с днями рождения выпадающими на текущую и следующую недели:

```
sqlite> select * from tab
where (strftime('%m-%d', dob)
    between strftime('%m-%d', date('now', 'weekday 0', '-6 days'))
    and
    strftime('%m-%d', date('now', 'weekday 0', '-6 days', '+13 days'))
);
user_id  dob
-------  ----------
1        1990-05-04
3        2001-05-10
4        2002-05-16
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно не +14 а +13, если +14 получается всего 15 дней

Comment: @13_Voin, точно! исправил)

Comment: Возникла небольшая проблема с вторника он начинает брать данные со следующий недели, то есть текущую пропускает. Наче нашёл выход разделить запрос на текущую (`between strftime('%m-%d', date('now','weekday 0', '-6 days'))
    and
    strftime('%m-%d', date('now','weekday 0'))
);`) и следующую (`between strftime('%m-%d', datetime('now','weekday 0', '+1 days'))
    and
    strftime('%m-%d', datetime('now','weekday 0', '+8 days'))
);`). Можешь проверить? Спасибо

Comment: @13_Voin, изменил ответ, но его нужно протестировать в воскресенье - не уверен как поведет себя `date('now','weekday 0', '-6 days')` в воскресенье...